# The differential of trace function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3809861/1034794) states that the differential of a trace function is given by

$d\text{Tr}(f(X)) = f'(X^T):dX$ where the colon $A:B$ means $\text{Tr}(A^TB)$.

How do we prove it? Does any know any reference/textbook that states this?

Comment: Look [here](https://swnydick.github.io/assets/reports/Schonemann_Trace_Derivatives_Presentation.pdf)

Comment: You can start from there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form